# Optional query param type in Spring WebMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, query-string

Spring allows to do Optional for RequestParams. How to do this for query parameters?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Page<Deal> getDeals(Optional<PageRange> pageRange) {
        return dealService.findDeals(pageRange.orElse(DEFAULT_PAGE_RANGE));
    }
```

The query params wrapper:

```
@Value
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PageRange {

    int page;
    int size;

}
```

This fails if either page or size is not passed. Why?

Comment: Did you try to leave away the `AllArgsConstructor` and simply put setters?

Comment: Then it works fine, but it's ugly :-)

Comment: IMHO it's not ugly, it's normal :)